# Android: How to get current device WiFi-direct name

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, device-name

In a P2P setting, I understand how to get another device's name, but how do I get my own device's name? (the one displayed in WiFi-direct under settings).

I have checked `WiFiManager`, `WiFiInfo`, and more with no success.

Comment: Can you edit your question & show codes ?

Comment: Not sure what to add... all I want to do is access the device's name, similar to in Bluetooth where you'd call `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getName()`

Comment: `WifiP2pDevice.deviceName` ? See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html)

Comment: How do you get the WifiP2pDevice for your own device?

Comment: Unforunately no - I chose to just store a "app-specific" Wi-Fi Direct password that would be broadcasted when hosting a Wi-Fi group

Answer (score 13):

After you turn on wifi on your device, it is send a WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION broadcast. You can catch this with a broadcast receiver and you can get a WifiP2pDevice object, that is your device.

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     WifiP2pDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);
     String thisDeviceName = device.deviceName;
 }
```

Comment: You will get this call when you register for the WifiP2pBroadcastReceiver, it doesn't matter if wifi is already on.

Comment: `device` is null, hence getting `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static String getHostName(String defValue) {
    try {
        Method getString = Build.class.getDeclaredMethod("getString", String.class);
        getString.setAccessible(true);
        return getString.invoke(null, "net.hostname").toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return defValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply in your broadcast receiver,

```
 if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) { 
        WifiP2pDevice myDevice =(WifiP2pDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);
        Log.d("Wifi Direct: My Device",myDevice.devicename); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the manager, you can use [WifiP2pManager.requestDeviceinfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager#requestDeviceInfo(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DeviceInfoListener)) with  the DeviceInfoListener

```
mManager.requestDeviceInfo(mChannel, wifiP2pDevice -> String deviceName = wifiP2pDevice.deviceName));
```

But it's only available from API29