# WiFi-Direct getting device name

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, wifi-direct

Is there a way to get my current Wifi-Direct device name without listening to WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION ? If wifi is already enabled I guess I cannot receive that intent.

I'm developing an app to create a WiFi direct group and share devices locations between peers. When I open a group I need to initialize a data structure, a map in the form of ( deviceName, lastLocation) with my location. A group is created by the user when pressing a button.

Comment: what are you doing? Explain briefly ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26997159/1978379 This answer says you still get it after register the WifiP2pBroadcastReceiver. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You will get *WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION*  when you register for the WifiP2pBroadcastReceiver, it doesn't matter if wifi is already on.

[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643989/android-how-to-get-current-device-wifi-direct-name/26997159#26997159)